# Checkboxes using docusign api which are selected and editable at same time

Tags: docusignapi

I have created checkbox using docusign api, i am having problem while making it selected and editable at same time.Please help me in this.

Comment: i am using below properties to make it selected and editable         tab.setSelected(Boolean.TRUE);
tab.setTemplateLocked(Boolean.FALSE);

Answer (score 0):

To make a tab editable by the signer/recipient, you need to set the **locked** property to **false**.  (i.e., The **templateLocked** property does something different altogether -- you don't need to set that property.)